# Rect.intersects is not working

Tags: java, android

I have an ArrayList of Rect that are defined by an x,y,x2,y2 value and another Rect that moves across the screen and is supposed to intersect the rectangles in the ArrayList. However, when the rectangles intersect, nothing is happening. Below is my relevant code:

```
public static ArrayList<Rect> rectangles = new ArrayList<Rect>(100);

 public static ArrayList<Rect> rectangles2 = new ArrayList<Rect>(90);

public static Rect intersected = new Rect();



 int bar_x = 32;

int bar_y = 653;

 int bar_x2 = 183;

 int bar_y2 = 648;

 int BarSpeed = 2;

Rect bar;

Paint paint;



public GameScreen(Game game) {

super(game);




// Initialize game objects here




  bar = new Rect();

 bar.set(bar_x, bar_y, bar_x2, bar_y2);

rectangles.add(new Rect(135,614,160,588));

    rectangles.add(new Rect(124,541,147,512));
for (Rect rect : rectangles) {

   if(Rect.intersects(bar, rect)) {

       Log.d("GameScreen", "intersected");

    intersected = rect;

    checkButtons();




  }

}



if (BarisMoving) {




  bar_y -= BarSpeed;

  bar_y2 -=BarSpeed;

  bar.set(bar_x, bar_y, bar_x2, bar_y2);

 }

}




private void checkButtons() {

 Log.d("GameScreen","Note and Bar Intersected");



KeyButton keybutton = new KeyButton();



  if (B1Pressed == keybutton.getB1() && B2Pressed == keybutton.getB2() && B3Pressed == keybutton.getB3()) {

      Log.i("GameScreenTest", "Correct");

      score++;

  } else {

      Log.i("GameScreenTest - Result", "Wrong");

      Log.i("GameScreenTest - Button Pressed", Boolean.toString(B1Pressed));

      Log.i("GameScreenTest - Button Required", Boolean.toString(keybutton.getB1()));

  }

}
```

In my LOGCAT, "intersected" is not being written. How can I make it so that the rectangles intersect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rect constructor](http://developer.android.com/intl/en/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#Rect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) takes (left,top,right,bottom). Looks like you're passing (left,top,width,height). Change these to (left+width) and (top+height) and you should get better results.

Comment: That sounds like an unrelated problem, so I suggest you check the line in the stack trace to see where you're accessing invalid elements.